# Is "mes" an accepted plural form of "me"?

Tags: grammatical-number, personal-pronouns

Is *mes* (the first two letters pronounced the same way as *me*, an alternate spelling is probably *me's*) an accepted plural form of *me*?

> There are other mes in other possible worlds.

Comment: The normal plural of *me* is *us*. But you could use *mes* to suggest that you had multiple personalities or some such thing.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure that the tags *plurals* or *pluralisation* should become *grammatical number*.

Comment: How about "me"s? If you put the "me" in quotes, it indicates that you are using "me" as a concept. After all, there can only be one you - from your own perspective. (If one of your other "me"s went to the store, you wouldn't say, "I went to the store.")

Comment: Only by Jar Jar.

Comment: There may be another ewe, but there's only one me.

Comment: @Oldbag: Funnily enough, I also thought about putting the "me" in quotation marks. But I feel a little uneasy pluralizing a quoted noun like that; for some reason "me"s looks more awkward to me than mes.

Comment: You can't write the plural "mes", because it looks funny.  It sounds okay, though.

Comment: How so, mes amis?

Comment: it depends on how schiz (https://psychcentral.com/quizzes/schizophrenia.htm) you are. i personally use me myself and I if that's all i want to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to find it used this way in published works. 
From [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=-TCpBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq=the%20%22mes%22%20in%20other%20worlds&source=bl&ots=7PLKV6kuWJ&sig=2tzCATrV-d-gD53hzjBNq29swaE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SWpYVZHuO8iGsAXenYCoBg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=mes&f=false) (bolding not in the original):

> Each decision that created a subtly different universe, created another of us, another of a nearly infinite number of **mes**, who added just a fraction more to our intellect and understanding.

– Paul Melko, "Ten Sigmas"

"Me" is being used here as a noun; pluralizing the pronoun "me" gives us "us" instead.

Using "me" as a noun like this is relatively rare compared to its use as a pronoun. But there are still numerous examples of this usage, as can be seen from this Google Books search of the phrase "[the me](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20me%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)".

The plural, "mes", is probably even rarer, since it is generally not needed outside of science fiction or speculative contexts.

As some have mentioned in the comments, it also has the downside of looking somewhat like it should be pronounced in the same way as "mess."

Answer (score 2):

Why not, "...an infinite number of selves"?

Though you would have to change,

"Each decision that created a subtly different universe, created another *self*, another of a nearly infinite number of *selves* who added just a fraction more to our intellect and understanding."

Answer (score 2):

I think that a more immediately recognizable spelling/punctuation of plural *me* would be *me's*. Here are some examples from Google Books search results. From John R. Mayer, [*Gilgamesh: A Reader*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0Ok5WbdWi3QC&pg=PA341&dq=me%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATi-AWoVChMI5634iZ_WxwIVUX6ICh3rpg5k#v=onepage&q=me%27s&f=false) (1997):

> When I address you, I also address myself. As I observe you I also observe myself. In this observational act, the inside of each of us, our subjective I's, become the outside of us, our objective **Me's**. As I am a Me to you, I become a Me to myself. When I as a subject speak to you, I also speak to me as an object.

From Anselm Strauss, [*Mirrors and Masks: The Search for Identity*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pig9i9eEWUMC&pg=PA59&dq=me%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAji-AWoVChMI5634iZ_WxwIVUX6ICh3rpg5k#v=onepage&q=me%27s&f=false) (1997):

> The I, as subject, in reviewing its **Me's** as objects, continually moves into a partially uncharted future; thus new I's and **Me's**—that is, appraising act and appraised acts—necessarily emerge.
>
> ...
>
> Some of these transactions consist of each person's responses to himself. It would be well here to recollect Reizler's remark that the "I" can respond to many "**me's**": among them the me of yesterday, tomorrow, several minutes ago, the me of the immediate present, and the me in general. In face-to-face situations, persons respond to various facets of themselves and their performances.

From Christa Metzger, [*Unemployed: A Journey Through the Dark Woods*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nxTCitMeQkYC&pg=PA25&dq=me%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAziqAWoVChMI2_Tx2qHWxwIVkoCSCh2PfgCi#v=onepage&q=me%27s&f=false) (2011):

> If I had only been able to — alloweed myself to — enjoy such carefree moments more in those days! But my mind was mostly judging and criticizing *me* for pursuing all these stupid little things to fill the big void left by not having a job. I began to wonder if there were two ***me's*** — the one criticizing and the one doing these things. It was as though I was observing myself acting in this different role.

And from Andre Depuis, [*Of Heterogeneous Disposition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8YF-AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA393&dq=me%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAjiqAWoVChMI2_Tx2qHWxwIVkoCSCh2PfgCi#v=onepage&q=me%27s&f=false) (2013):

> I could sell my book modestly, if at all, and it didn't matter.
>
> I'm sure there are other '**me's**'. Like me, but different.
>
> Better than me at being me.

As the first two examples suggest, one advantage of the spelling *me's* is that it makes a more natural pairing with *I's*, which is a much more appealing plural form of *I* than the alternative *Is* is.

In any case, I get the impression from Google Books search results that *me's* is a more common plural form of *me* than *mes* is (although both spellings produce numerous false matches for such things as contracted "me is" (*me's*) and French *my* (*mes*). That's the spelling I would use.

Comment: Good examples to support your point. To me, "me's" looks like it has a greengrocer's apostrophe though. "I's" looks more acceptable since it is a single letter, and "Is" would obviously clash to some extent with the already-existing word "is."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know English, but I'd like to use "mes". :D Of course it sounds irrational and wrong, because it's impossible. But "me's" sounds grammatically more like a genitive because of the ' (even if "my" would be correct).